# 'xcrun xcresulttool export --path' file format

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

[image]

I used the xcresulttool export the file, but the structure of the file is like this, who knows what the data structure of the file is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the output as JSON using the `format` options:

```sh
xcrun xcresulttool get --path "~/path/to/file.xcresult" --format json
```

Currently, the only two formats that are supported are either `json` or `raw`. `raw` is the default, leading to output like you posted.

Comment: Thanks, json is easy to read, but the data structure is not convenient for my requirements development. Finally,I using antlr to do the semantic analysis

Comment: Yeah, the resulting data structure is a nightmare. I ended up using a Swift script, with types generated by https://quicktype.io.